# Lighten my cms loading

Tags: php

I am creating a cms system and so far so good. But as i go further with my project i develloped alot of plugins for my cms like a guestbook, calendar, comments, events, blog,...
Now every plugin is loaded in my index.php file with the require function.
A plugin gets loaded like this.

```
// START PLUGINS //
/////////////
// COUNTER
ob_start();
require 'plugins/counter/counter.php';
$counter = ob_get_clean();
```

and the plugins gets displayed only on the pages with the correct TAG like this

```
$template = file_get_contents('./templates/' . $default_template . '/template.php');
$search = array('[[SITE_TITLE]]', '[[PAGE_TITLE]]', '[[PAGE_CONTENT]]', '[[MENU_LINKS]]', '[[DEFAULT_TEMPLATE]]', '[[COUNTER]]');
$replace = array($site_title, $page_title, $page_content, $newresult, $default_template, $counter);
echo $template
```

Now, this is the main structure, but in the last few months i have like 35 plugins now. The require plugins gets heavy and i am affraid that my website will go slow with lots of traffic.

Is there an other way i can "require" all the plugins but with less effect on my website speed?
thx for any suggestions. I have been looking arround here but found no solution yet.

Comment: Are you having a performance problem or do you _think_ you are having a performance problem? Without profiling your code, we can't tell you the answer.

Comment: [cmslink](http://fluxie.x10.mx) people tell me they can load the website very slow, but on my pc it runs smoothly

Comment: Your content seems to be taking the bulk of the time. combine your js into a single file, and do the same with your css. Load your javascript at the bottom of the page. Make them cachable. If you think there is a bottleneck in the php, then use xdebug to find the slow parts. If you don't know how to make those parts faster post specific questions about them.

Comment: You are making on the order of 50 http requests for an uncached site load. Get that number way down. There are a lot of places you could be using css sprites for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no silver bullet for optimization. I suggest you turn on [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) profiler and find the bottleneck. Then eliminate it.

Also you can follow some common optimization techniques.

1. A good resource on Stackoverflow.com. [Tactics for using PHP in a high-load site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675/tactics-for-using-php-in-a-high-load-site?rq=1)
2. A [page](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php) from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic autoload function to require classes only when necessary. Check out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php